# Scala: implicitly convert Option to Option of implicit class

Tags: scala

How to implicitly convert Option[A] to Option[B], where B is an implicit class of A?

In the following code only `converter1` works, but the return type is not generic:

```
implicit class Test(val i: Int)

implicit def converter0[A, B](opt: Option[A])(implicit f: A => B): Option[B] = {
  opt.map(f)
}

implicit def converter1[A](opt: Option[A])(implicit f: A => Test): Option[Test] = {
  opt.map(f)
}

implicit def converter2[B](opt: Option[Int])(implicit f: Int => B): Option[B] = {
  opt.map(f)
}

val b: Option[Int] = Option(1)
val a: Option[Test] = b
```

Comment: Would marking your implicit classes with a marker trait work for you? if you make `B <: MarkerTrait` things will work. Running your example in the compiler with `-Ytyper-debug` it appears there is an implicit in Scala itself `implicit def $conforms` in Predef is causing converter0 to resolve incorrectly.